# Windows 8 computer will not find wireless networks

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1

I'm looking for ideas before I wipe this machine, which I do not want to have to do. My win8 laptop stopped seeing my wireless networks all of the sudden after 2 years. Hardwired of course still works, the wireless nic shows up as disabled in adapter settings and right clicking on it to enable it appears like it is working, but it never enables and never works

Things I've done
Uninstalled and reinstalled the on board nic
Updated the driver for the on board nic
sfc /scannow - problems found but couldn't be fixed
netsh winsock reset
safemode with networking (no difference)
installed a usb nic - did not work nor would it enable
the windows wifi troubleshooting utility - no help
disabling my av and software firewall

I do not have any system restore points available and am open to ideas. Thanks

Comment: Could you possibly be overlooking a little physical wifi enable/disable switch somewhere on the laptop? Or some laptops toggle that through something like a Shift + Fn key.

Comment: ^^^this. Also, you could gain some knowledge by booting to a linux live cd and seeing if the wifi works there

Comment: The hardware switch is actually a function key and yes the wifi is enabled via that. It will toggle between air plane mode and wifi.

I'll try the Linux live disc to confirm OS corruption